# How to use Swift NSRegularExpression to get uppercased letter?

Tags: swift, nsregularexpression

I have a string like this:

`"te_st"` and like to replace **`all underscores followed by a character`** with the uppercased version of this character.

---

From `"te_st"` --> Found (regex: `"_."`) --------replace with next char (+ uppercase (`"s"`->`"S"`)--------> `"teSt"` 

From `"te_st"` ---> to `"teSt"`
From `"_he_l_lo"` ---> to `"HeLLo"`
From `"an_o_t_h_er_strin_g"` ---> to `"anOTHErStrinG"`

... but I can not really get it working using Swift's `NSRegularExpression` like this small snipped does:

```
var result = "te_st" // result should be teSt
result = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "_*").stringByReplacingMatches(in: result, range: NSRange(0..<result.count), withTemplate: ("$1".uppercased()))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no regular syntax to convert a match to uppercase. The code you posted is attempting to convert the string `$1` to uppercase which is of course just `$1`. It isn't attempting to convert the value represented by the `$1` match at runtime.

Here's another approach using a regular expression to find the `_` followed by a lowercase letter. Those are enumerated and replaced with the uppercase letter.

```
extension String {
    func toCamelCase() -> String {
        let expr = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "_([a-z])")
        var res = self
        for match in expr.matches(in: self, range: NSRange(0..<res.count)).reversed() {
            let range = Range(match.range, in: self)!
            let letterRange = Range(match.range(at: 1), in: self)!
            res.replaceSubrange(range, with: self[letterRange].uppercased())
        }

        return res
    }
}

print("te_st".toCamelCase())
print("_he_l_lo".toCamelCase())
print("an_o_t_h_er_strin_g".toCamelCase())
```

This outputs:

> teSt
>   HeLLo
>   anOTHErStrinG

Comment: but as in documentaion of regular expression by apple "$n" will be replaced by the result.In this case $1 will be replaced by the first match and its a string.So why cant we use a method on a string?

Comment: No need to pass an empty array for the options as it is already the default value in both cases

Comment: @MuhammadZohaibEhsan Because the requirement isn't a simple replacement. The replacement needs to be converted to uppercase. That can't be done using a simple regular expression.

Comment: So we cant use methods on the template.The replacement string should be used as template.The result cant be manipulated?

Comment: @MuhammadZohaibEhsan No, there is no simple syntax to manipulate the template result. That's what the OP tried to do by using `uppercased`.

Comment: @Jonas0000 What should be `rangeAt(1)`? Do you mean the user of `range(at: 1)`? `rangeAt(1)` looks like Swift 2 syntax.

Comment: rageAt(1) is Swift 4 Syntax my friend :) @rmaddy

Comment: I still have no idea what you mean. What is the rangeSt you are referring to?

Comment: `old: match.range(at: 1)`  | `new: match.rangeAt(1)` !

Comment: @Jonas0000 Huh? Look at the current documentation for `NSTextCheckingResult`. The current (as of Swift 3) method is `range(at:)`. What documentation are you referring to that indicates that `rangeAt(_:)` is "new"?

Comment: > https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit/issues/171 > https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit/issues/168 > Xcode says "range(at:) has been renamed to rangeAt(1) ". I hope you are happy know?

Comment: @Jonas0000 The Swift 4/iOS 11 documentation clearly states the current method is named `range(at:)`. The code in my answer was tested in a Swift 4 playground in Xcode 9.2 and `range(at:)` works just fine. Use which ever of the two works for you in your app.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one implementation using NSRegularExpression. I use group match to get the character after _ and capitalize it and replace the string.

```
func capitalizeLetterAfterUnderscore(string: String) -> String {
  var capitalizedString = string

  guard let regularExpression = try?  NSRegularExpression(pattern: "_(.)") else {
                                                            return capitalizedString
  }

  let matches = regularExpression.matches(in: string,
                                          options: .reportCompletion,
                                          range: NSMakeRange(0, string.count))

  for match in matches {
      let groupRange = match.range(at: 1)
      let index = groupRange.location

      let characterIndex = string.index(string.startIndex,
                                          offsetBy: index)
      let range = characterIndex ... characterIndex

      let capitalizedCharacter = String(capitalizedString[characterIndex]).capitalized
      capitalizedString = capitalizedString.replacingCharacters(in: range,
                                                                with: capitalizedCharacter)
  }

  capitalizedString = capitalizedString.replacingOccurrences(of: "_", with: "")
  return capitalizedString
}



capitalizeLetterAfterUnderscore(string: "an_o_t_h_er_strin_g") // anOTHErStrinG
```

And here is other one without using regular expression. I made extension for method which could also be reused.

```
extension String {

  func indexes(of character: String) -> [Index] {
    precondition(character.count == 1, "character should be single letter string")

    return enumerated().reduce([]) { (partial, component) in

      let currentIndex = index(startIndex,
                               offsetBy: component.offset)
      return String(self[currentIndex]) == character
                                  ? partial + [currentIndex]
                                  : partial
    }
  }

  func capitalizeLetter(after indexes: [Index]) -> String {
    var modifiedString = self

    for currentIndex in indexes {

      guard let letterIndex = index(currentIndex,
                                           offsetBy: 1,
                                           limitedBy: endIndex)
        else { continue }

      let range = letterIndex ... letterIndex

      modifiedString = modifiedString.replacingCharacters(in: range,
                                                          with: self[range].capitalized)
    }

    return modifiedString
  }
}

let string = "an_o_t_h_er_strin_g"
let newString = string.capitalizeLetter(after: string.indexes(of: "_"))
                      .replacingOccurrences(of: "_",with: "")
```

Comment: Working - looks fine. Thanks Sandeep

Comment: `String.Index` inside a String extension method is redundant. `func indexes(of character: String) -> [Index]`

Comment: and Index has a specific method to offset 1 position called `index(after:)` `index(after: currentIndex)`

Comment: @LeoDabus Anything else that you see could be improved. Please write it, I can learn from it :)

Comment: I am not running your code. Just overlooking at it thats all I can say by now.

Comment: You can remove `if indexOfLetterAfter >= endIndex {
        continue
      }` if you use `index(, offsetBy:, limitedBy: )`using the string `endIndex` as the limit. it returns an optional index

Comment: My bad you can’t use index(after:) method in your case. Just use the limitedBy in a guard statement

Comment: Why not, it can be used here       let indexOfLetterAfter = index(currentIndex, offsetBy: 1)

Comment: Anyway, guard let is better since I am using comparison below the line so, limitedBy makes more sense.

Comment: You can’t increment an index past the endIndex. The edge case to test it would be an underscore as the last character in a string

Comment: Ok, it catches it anyway in this case, since we are using indexes from the same string and the indexes array cannot have something past endIndex.

Comment: @LeoDabus Checkout the changes now, a bit better :) Thanks for helping to improve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string `range(of:, options:, range:)` method with `.regularExpression` options to match the occurrences of `"_[a-z]"` and replace the subranges iterating the ranges found at reversed order by the character at the index after the range lowerbound uppercased:

```
let string = "an_o_t_h_er_strin_g"
let regex = "_[a-z]"
var start = string.startIndex
var ranges:[Range<String.Index>] = []

while let range = string.range(of: regex, options: .regularExpression, range: start..<string.endIndex) {
    start = range.upperBound
    ranges.append(range)
}
var finalString = string
for range in ranges.reversed() {
    finalString.replaceSubrange(range, with: String(string[string.index(after: range.lowerBound)]).uppercased())
}
print(finalString)   // "anOTHErStrinG\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it is converting the string "$1" to upper case (which is, unsurprisingly unchanged, just "$1") and using "$1" as the template. If you want to use regex, you will have to enumerate through matches yourself.

The alternative is to split the string by `_` characters and uppercase the first character of every substring (except the first) and joining it back together using `reduce`:

```
let input = "te_st"

let output = input.components(separatedBy: "_").enumerated().reduce("") { $0 + ($1.0 == 0 ? $1.1 : $1.1.uppercasedFirst()) }
```

Or, if your goal isn't to write code as cryptic as most regex, we can make that a tad more legible:

```
let output = input
    .components(separatedBy: "_")
    .enumerated()
    .reduce("") { result, current in
        if current.offset == 0 {
            return current.element      // because you don’t want the first component capitalized
        } else {
            return result + current.element.uppercasedFirst()
        }
}
```

Resulting in:

> teSt

Note, that uses this extension for capitalizing the first character:

```
extension String {
    func uppercasedFirst(with locale: Locale? = nil) -> String {
        guard count > 0 else { return self }
        return String(self[startIndex]).uppercased(with: locale) + self[index(after: startIndex)...]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do sort of dynamic conversion with `NSRegularExpression`, you can subclass `NSRegularExpression` and override `replacementString(for:in:offset:template:)`:

```
class ToCamelRegularExpression: NSRegularExpression {
    override func replacementString(for result: NSTextCheckingResult, in string: String, offset: Int, template templ: String) -> String {
        if let range = Range(result.range(at: 1), in: string) {
            return string[range].uppercased()
        } else {
            return super.replacementString(for: result, in: string, offset: 0, template: templ)
        }
    }
}

func toCamelCase(_ input: String) -> String { //Make this a String extension if you prefer...
    let regex = try! ToCamelRegularExpression(pattern: "_(.)")
    return regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: input, options: [], range: NSRange(0..<input.utf16.count), withTemplate: "$1")
}
print(toCamelCase("te_st")) //-> teSt
print(toCamelCase("_he_l_lo")) //-> HeLLo
print(toCamelCase("an_o_t_h_er_strin_g")) //-> anOTHErStrinG
```